# Using ROS2 for autonomous driving

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am currently developing a prototype for a simple autonomous function using ROS2. However, I do not dive deep into the ROS2 functionalities rather I am exploiting the DDS functionalities.

To have a more deeper insight of ROS2, I want to extend this prototype or maybe start with a new one.

I saw an excellent tutorial for this using ROS and Gazebo [here](https://github.com/osrf/car_demo) but I guess I cannot extend it to ROS2.

I have certain questions regarding the same:

1. Do we have support for Gazebo in ROS2 ?
2. I already have a running setup wherein I am using my own tool for environment simulation as well as for vehicle dynamic simulation. How can I bring in ROS2 here ?
3. Do you have some other ideas to use ROS2 for autonomous driving. I am open to all ideas :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296854/using-ros2-for-autonomous-driving/) by [aks](https://answers.ros.org/users/34222/aks/) on ROS Answers with karma: 667 on 2018-07-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

1. I don't think there is gazebo for ROS2 yet. If you have a look at the roadmap: https://github.com/ros2/ros2/wiki/Roadmap it should be ported in the December 2018 release.
2. You can compile the ROS2 shared libraries using the ROS2 build system and include them in your project if you wish. If you are using gcc: use the flags -I for the includes, -L for the libraries location and -l for the library name you need to use.
3. Unfortunately, no :(

---

Originally posted by [pokitoz](https://answers.ros.org/users/32070/pokitoz/) with karma: 527 on 2018-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1